# GeoServer client-side caching

Tags: caching, client-side, geoserver

Currently I have a ImageMosaic layer, that I would like to cache on the client-side.
It looks like (googling) in the response headers from Geoserver, information regarding caching should be present.

How would I set that up with GeoServer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using WMTS requests? it should be on by default

Comment: It is WMS requests. .

Comment: switch to using WMTS then